# UIActivityIndicator view on navigation left bar button item doesn't show for iOS 13.0 device?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uinavigationitem, uiactivityindicatorview

UIActivityIndicator view on navigation left bar button item doesn't show for iOS 13.0 device: 
Here is the code:

```
let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
activityIndicator.tintColor = UIColor.white
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: activityIndicator)
self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(barButton, animated: true)
```

Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: This code works fine, are you sure you have `navigationItem`?

Comment: Does it work for other iOS versions? Is the code actually executing?

Comment: This code exactly works fine on iOS 12.0, but doesn't work on iOS 13.0 device